# delete images from internal and external storage?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and I want to create a small app for personal use, where I want to access my phones (Android) internal and external storage, to get all images and delete them if I please.

At first I tried a managed project with expo and managed to delete images from my internal storage via the Expo Media Library. The only problem was, I couldn't delete images on my SD-card, which is why I setup a bare project with react-native with all AndroidSDK stuff.

After some grindy hours I managed to fire up the react-native version but at this point I am unable to delete any images, be it on internal or external storage (on an emulator).

I tried:

- Expo MediaLibrary (works for actually getting the images and delete works in a managed project on internal storage)
- react-native-fs (unlink did nothing, eventhough the uri is correct)
- react-native-fetch-blob FS (unlink keeps throwing an error, saying it couldn't delete the file with the code: EUNSPECIFIED, eventhough the uri is correct)

Does anyone know, if and how I can delete images reliably from internal and external storage from my Android phone? Or is it a problem with the emulator, that somehow prevents the app from deleting it? Do I have to settle with the limited functionallity of the managed version, which can delete images from my internal storage?

Answer (score 1):

```
Using this code you have delete file from your external storage.
more information for RNFetchBlob.fs
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob

```
remove() {
    let dirs =
      Platform.OS === "android"
        ? `/storage/emulated/0/Folder_name/${File_name}`
        : `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/Folder_name/${File_name}`;

    RNFetchBlob.fs
      .unlink(dirs)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("file is deleted");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Like I said, I tried RNFetchBlob's unlink()-function and could not delete files from an external storage (at least on an emulator) and got the error code: EUNSPECIFIED
I doublechecked the paths to the files as well